# Multi index can access data in contract but (RPC) cleos get table is empty

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index

Here is the code

[image]

I deployed it with the following command:

```
cleos set contract . demo.wast demo.abi -p demo
```

and query it with:

```
cleos get table demo demo demos
```

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef multi_index<N(demos), d> demo_table
```

the first parameter is table name, please keep same with your abi description